# logging in symfony 2.3

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to write my own messages to the log in Symfony 2.3, from anywhere, and not just the Controller (which I realize you can just do a `"$this->get('logger')"`.

I've seen that in Symfony 1 you can use `sfContext`, but that class no longer seems to be a viable choice in 2.3.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should register your service with [Monolog](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#monolog-logger) as a dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Symfony2 has Service-oriented architecture (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) and `logger` is one of service (by default Monolog). In controller you have access to service via `$this->get('service_name')`. Here is more info about service container: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#what-is-a-service-container. If you wanna use `logger` in another service you have to define service and inject `logger` service. Example:

```
# section with defined service in your config.yml file (by default in config.yml)
services:
    # your service name
    my_service:
        # your class name
        class: Fully\Qualified\Loader\Class\Name
        # arguments passed to service constructor. In this case @logger
        arguments: ["@logger"]
        # tags, info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html
        tags:
            - { name: monolog.logger, channel: acme }
```

Additionally you should familiarize with dependency injection docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html

I hope that helped. If not, please let me know where exactly you want to use `logger`.